# get-childitem find files in folders with same names

Tags: powershell, path, get-childitem

I need to check that all files in folders with the naming ".policy" is ether 'azureDeploy.parameters.json' or 'azureDeploy.json'

if i only want it to check one folder i just give the full path as here:

```
            $azureDeployFiles = @('azureDeploy.parameters.json', 'azureDeploy.json')        
            (Get-ChildItem -path ..\..\fes\.policy -file -Recurse).name | Should -BeIn $azureDeployFiles
```

and that works. But i have multiple folders called something like `'.\..\..\.policy'` and i would like to check if all the folders with that naming only contains files with the naming 'azureDeploy.parameters.json' or 'azureDeploy.json'

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path .\MyPath -Include $azureDeployFiles -Recurse`. Give this a shot

Comment: then I just get all the files with that naming. I want to check if it is only those two kind of names/files in every .policy folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify 'only files in folders named X' with `Where-Object` on the `Directory` property:

```
$azureDeployFiles = @('azureDeploy.parameters.json', 'azureDeploy.json')
Get-ChildItem -path ..\..\ -Recurse -File | 
  Where Directory -Like "*\.policy" | 
    # example checking file names with -In
    Foreach { $_.Name -In $azureDeployFiles }
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment. . .with a little help from the pipeline, we can use `Where-Object` to filter for directories with that specific name:

```
$azureDeployFiles = @('azureDeploy.parameters.json', 'azureDeploy.json') 
Get-ChildItem -Path '.\MyPath' -Include $azureDeployFiles -Recurse | 
    Where-Object Directory -Like '*\.Policy'
```